# How to make Eclipse's dropdown menu align left (back to normal)?

Tags: eclipse

I just install Eclipse recently, and its dropdown menu items are aligning right.  Is there a way to make it align left?  Not sure if I clicked something to make it reverse, but after couple hours of searching, I still cannot find any clue.

[image: Reverse alignment!!!]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally realize this is a problem with Windows 10 itself and not eclipse.

https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-windows-10-opens-right-click-context-menu-to-left-side/